# How to change the value of a button through CSS

Tags: html, css, button

So here's the code:

```
<form id="my-button" action="#" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="sample-button" value="Hello">
</form>
```

I need to be able to change the value through CSS.
No clicking or hovering. Just need to replace it through CSS.

I tried doing this, but it's not working.

```
#my-button input[type=submit]:before{
    content:"";
}
#my-button input[type=submit]:after{
    content:"HI";
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to change it via CSS?

Comment: I don't have any access with the main file. I'm trying to come up with a solution through CSS. :/

Comment: Why don't you do that by JavaScript? `document.querySelector('input[name="sample-button"]').value = 'HI'`

Comment: You can try `$("#my-button  input[type='submit']").attr('value', 'HI');`

Comment: You cannot change the value of a button using CSS, you could change what is displayed ON the button, but not the value itself. Use Javascript.

Answer (score 10):

If you want it for display/appearance purposes, you can try something like this, **using pure css**:

[Example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Lp2j12d/)

it won't change the actual submit's value, but for display purposes it works fine.

```css
input[type=submit] {
  color: transparent;
}

#my-button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#my-button:after {
  content: "World";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="my-button" action="#" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="sample-button" value="Hello">
</form>
```

Comment: The OP said `I don't have any access with the main file` which means s/he couldn't modify the HTML file directly.

Comment: This will just change the DISPLAY of the button, not the VALUE itself.

Comment: This is the same for this example/question , this is what OP trying to achieve.

Comment: No, it's not, OP wants to change the value of the button.

Comment: In general, you don't need submit's value for something else, but for display purposes.

Comment: So you placed form's pseudo-element over the button. How do you now click on the button?

Comment: @Glen Kemarsky nice catch. `pointer-events: none;` has been added.

Answer (score 3):

```css
button:hover:before {
  content: "Button after hover>>"
}

button:after {
  content: "Button before hover"
}

button:hover:after {
  content: ""
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

That really isn't what CSS is for.

CSS is for styling your content; HTML is for the actual content itself.

If you need to modify the content after the HTML has loaded, then that's what Javascript is for.

So the real answer to your question is: either modify the HTML directly, or use Javascript.
you can use

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#my-button input").val("Hi");
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

1) You can't just "change" some values with css. You can do something on events like :hover/:focus, but you can't affect elements like it's javascript.

2) :before and :after are individual elements inside parent element, which are NOT the same as your element.

3) And most important part - input element CAN'T have :before/:after elements.

4) You need access to html/js if you want to change anything.

Answer (score -1):

If you are still listening, you can do this:

```
<style>
    .btn { display: none; }
    .btn:before {
      content: "+";
      display: inline;
    }
</style>

<button><span class="btn">Next</span></button>
```